# Accessing a variable from a different class - custom dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a dialog that will get the a social security number (or simular input) from a pop up dialog, but when I try I get an error saying that the class does not have that attribute. Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        b = Button(text="Click for social dialog", command=self.getSocial)
        b.grid(row=0, column=0)
    def getSocial(self):
        d = socialDialog(root)
        print d.social
class socialDialog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.top = Toplevel()
        Label(self.top, text='Social Security #: ').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry = Entry(self.top)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.top.bind('<Key>', self.formatData)
        self.top.bind('<Return>', self.ok)
    def formatData(self, master):
        currentData = self.entry.get()
        if len(currentData) == 3:
            self.entry.insert(3, '-')
        elif len(currentData) == 6:
            self.entry.insert(6, '-')
        elif len(currentData) > 11:
            self.entry.delete(-1, END)
    def ok(self, master):
        self.social = self.entry.get()
        self.top.destroy()
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out this time, but it is much easier to help you with an error if you print the error stack trace - it has valuable debugging information in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `print` is executed immediately after the dialog is shown, because the dialog is not shown modally.

To fix that, try something like this:

```
d = socialDialog(root)
root.wait_window(d.top)
print d.social
```

But note that the error will still occur if the dialog is closed without entering anything. To prevent that, make sure the `social` attribute has a default value:

```
class socialDialog:
    social = None
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `socialDialog` class is only assigned a `social` attribute **after** you press Return, which invokes the `ok` method.  Therefore when you call `getSocial`, which instantiates a `socialDialog`, and then immediately access the `social` attribute, the `social` attribute in the `socialDialog` instance doesn't exist yet.

I'm not sure what your long term goals for this code are, but an immediate fix would be to change the `getSocial` function thusly:

```
def getSocial(self):
    d = socialDialog(root)
    #  print d.social
```

then add

```
print self.social
```

to the `ok` method.